# Filling a Array List from the eliments of some another Array Lists.

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList object filled with a number of ArrayList objects. Some entries are **null** and I want to put only the values of **not null ArrayLists** in to a single **ArrayList**. I'm talking about something like below.

```
{null,[p1,p2,p3],[p2,p5,p6],[p4]}
```

And as the final needed out put is something like this.

```
[p1,p2,p3,p2,p5,p6,p4]
```

The **ArrayList object of ArrayList objects** is created from a `hash map object`. My code segment is as below. But there is something wrong with it.

```
Collection<ArrayList<MyProduct>> tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyProduct>>();

            tmp= orderAdap.values();

            ArrayList<MyProduct> flattenList = new ArrayList<MyProduct>();
            for(ArrayList<MyProduct> list : tmp){
                for(MyProduct i : list)

                    if(i!=null){
                    lstStyle.add(i);
                    }
            }
```

So can someone help me. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: "But there is something wrong with it"...please be much more specific. Are you trying to add the items to `flattenList`?

Comment: Finally wanna add to a ArrayList.

Comment: Could you please tell us, what's happening witht he output, is there any error being thrown?

Comment: You might want to add a null check before calling the inner loop if (list!=null) proceed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this

```
tmp.remove(Collections.singleton(null));
for(ArrayList<MyProduct> list : tmp){         
     lstStyle.addAll(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addAll()`

```
for(ArrayList<MyProduct> list : tmp) {
    if(list!=null)
         lstStyle.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add only the unique elements from your lists of arraylist. I would suggest that when you are iterating over your lists, after null check get all the elements from the list and add it to a final set (e.g hashset). Once you get the set (that will contain the unique elements from all the arraylists), convert it back to a list.